# Geo-reference vector data with GCP and target area

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, ground-control

I have to geo-reference village maps(vector shapefiles) with the help of GCPs. In the transformation, the areas of the polygons need to match closely with their target values.

Is there a QGIS plugin that takes into the GCPs and areas for geo-referencing?

If not, then what kind of transformation and error function should I use to write a custom plugin?

The standard geo-referencer tool only takes GCPs as input.

Comment: Select the target coordinate system to match with the source data and the areas should match as well.

Comment: @user30184 I have been keeping the coordinate system the same for the source and transformed map. 

The target areas are in a separate file. There are inherent problems with the map because of which the transformed area does not match the target area. I am looking for a way to include the target areas with GCPs in the transformation process itself.

Comment: The area is computed by the coordinates of the vertices mathematically and considering also the coordinate system. When you set the ground control points and select the type of transformation the area comes as given. I think that what you can do is to manipulate your GCPs, or move the georeferenced vertices manually by digitizing, or use some image processing program that have tools for manual warping https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/warp-images-shapes-paths.html.